# How many elements in common on multiple lists?

Tags: r

Hi I'm observing a dataset which have a column named "genres" of string vectors that contain all tags of genres the film has, I want to create a plot that shows the popularity of all genres.

```
structure(list(anime_id = c("10152", "11061", "11266", "11757", 
"11771"), Name.x = c("Kimi ni Todoke 2nd Season: Kataomoi", "Hunter 
 x Hunter (2011)", 
 "Ao no Exorcist: Kuro no Iede", "Sword Art Online", "Kuroko no 
Basket"
), genres = list("Romance", c("Action", " Adventure", " Fantasy"
), "Fantasy", c("Action", " Adventure", " Fantasy", " Romance"
), "Sports")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

initially the genres column is a string with genres divided by comma . for example : ['action', 'drama', 'fantasy']. To work with I run this code to edit the column :

```
 AnimeList2022new$genres <- gsub("\\[|\\]|'" , "",                                               
   as.character(AnimeList2022new$genres))
 AnimeList2022new$genres <- strsplit( AnimeList2022new$genres, 
   ",")
```

I don't know how to compare all the vectors in order to know how many times a tags appear
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsYib.png)

I'm trying with group_by and summarise

```
genresdata <-MyAnimeList %>%
   group_by(genres) %>%
   summarise( count = n() ) %>%
   arrange( -count)
```

but obviously this code group similar vectors and not similar string contained in the vectors.
this is the output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARaON.png)

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. How do you define "popularity"? Are you trying to count the number of times a specific genre appears in your data?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to do that. for example how many times  "Action" appears in the whole column

Comment: Can you provide code so that we can create this same data frame? Providing code will make your question "reproducible," which will help us answer your problem. I think with the code to make your data frame, I can help.

Comment: hi, sorry i'm new.  I find this dataset on kaggle and I edit it in order to have a vector of genres. But I don't have any idea of how can I work with it.  @generic https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/vishalmane10/anime-dataset-2022

Comment: The `dput()` command makes a copy/pasteable version of an R object. If you run `dput(MyAnimeList[1:5, ])`, we'll get a copy/pasteable version of the first 5 rows of `MyAnimeList`. Just run that and put it in the question.

Comment: Edit your code so that it includes the creation of your data frame, not just the counting section. 

This is important so that: a) your question is reproducible, and b) we answer your question correctly. It looks like you don't create the data frame in a way that works with tidyverse R. There should not be lists of strings in each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `genres` column is of class `list`, so it sounds like you want the `length()` of reach row in it. Generally, we could do that like this:

```
MyAnimeList %>%
  mutate(n_genres = sapply(genres, length))
```

But this is a special case where there is a nice convenience function `lengths()` (notice the `s` at the end) built-in to R that gives us the same result, so we can simply do

```
MyAnimeList %>%
  mutate(n_genres = lengths(genres))
```

The above will give the number of genres for each row.

In the comments I see you say you want *"for example how many times "Action" appears in the whole column"*. For that, we can `unnest()` the genre list column and then count:

```
library(tidyr)
MyAnimeList %>% 
  unnest(genres) %>% 
  count(genres)
# # A tibble: 7 × 2
#   genres           n
#   <chr>        <int>
# 1 " Adventure"     2
# 2 " Fantasy"       2
# 3 " Romance"       1
# 4 "Action"         2
# 5 "Fantasy"        1
# 6 "Romance"        1
# 7 "Sports"         1
```

Do notice that some of your genres have leading white space--it's probably best to solve this problem "upstream" whenever the genre column was created, but we could do it now using `trimws` to trim whitespace:

```
MyAnimeList %>%
  unnest(genres) %>% 
  count(trimws(genres))
# # A tibble: 5 × 2
#   `trimws(genres)`     n
#   <chr>            <int>
# 1 Action               2
# 2 Adventure            2
# 3 Fantasy              3
# 4 Romance              2
# 5 Sports               1
```

Comment: thank you so much, I see now the second part of your answer. (sorry)